# Bulk removal of file name after an underscore

Tags: bulk-rename

How do I get  2114_1_e44db1eb-5700-49b9-b5db-b952bf73d5c21254f617-a970-443e-aded-9608a648c7a3.mp4 to just 2114_1.mp4?
I want to delete all text and numbers after and including the second_

Comment: 100% duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1660834/how-do-i-delete-text-after-an-underscore-or-before-and-underscore Please read the comments and act accordingly. Except for the title you have not changed anything in your question. Also you don't tell us what OS you use.

Comment: What you need sir is a utility that supports ***regular expressions***.  [There are many of them out there](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bulk+renamer+regular+expressions).  Learning how to write a regular expression (which I will not do for you but someone else might) is a PITA but VERY VERY POWERFUL and would solve this with ease.  You should learn ;)

Comment: Sorry... @Robert .. I didn't due diligence in searching this here before posting my comment. :)

Comment: Sorry for making this more confusing then it need to be I'm sure. I'm greener then green with this subject matter.